In next.js, upgrading pages -> app router incrementally, how to share state with context provider?
I'm trying an incremental upgrade from pages to app router with a next.js project.
I have a <SessionProvider> in my _app that uses localStorage in combination with useState to store my session token.
Something like this:
const useLocalStorage = <T>(key: string, defaultValue: T) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    let currentValue;

    try {
      currentValue = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(key) || String(defaultValue)
      );
    } catch (error) {
      currentValue = defaultValue;
    }

    return currentValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value, key]);

  return [value, setValue];
};

…

const [sessionToken, setSessionToken] = useLocalStorage<string | null>("session_token", null);

Problem I think I have is that this SessionProvider is rendered in both the old /pages/_app.page.tsx as well as in the new /app/layout.tsx - that being different instances - having different state. So even if the localStorage is shared, the internal state is not.
If I now have a protected page under the app router that redirects to a login page under the old page router, the following seem to happen if I'm debugging this right:
The app routers context provider is initalized without a value. Seeing that the user is not logged in redirects to the login page under /pages where the user logs in, but under another context provider instance in the component tree. Then redirecting back to the first protected page, the local-storage is not re-read from the first context provider and state has not been updated by the login.
So the way useLocalStorage is used is not reactive from local storage and therefore only works as a singleton with write reactivity to local storage.
So:

Is there anywhere in next I can put a wrapping component layout that is shared between app router and pages router? So I can have the same ContextProvider between both?
Or is there a simpler way to do this without going into signals or singleton state?
Or how do I typically do this in React if I can't share the component hierarchy?

I see I can possibly use https://usehooks.com/uselocalstorage that seems to be reactive from localstorage: https://github.com/uidotdev/usehooks/blob/dfa6623fcc2dcad3b466def4e0495b3f38af962b/index.js#L616
but I rather have something simpler…
